# Stripe not working after asp.net 2.1 upgrade

Tags: c#

I have a Stripe integration which is working fine in my asp.net core 2.1 application.
However when I upgrade to .Net 3.0 it stops working.
The only error I get is
:44371/ajax/confirm_payment:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

I’ve updated the Stripe.Net and tried upgrading to 3.0 and 6.0
But no joy.

The ajax/confirm_payment calls this action...

```
[Route("/ajax/confirm_payment")] 
public class ConfirmPaymentController : Controller
{
    public ConfirmPaymentController(IConfiguration iConfig)
    {
        configuration = iConfig;
    }



    public IConfiguration configuration { get; set; }

 
    public IActionResult Index(ConfirmPaymentRequest request)
    {
        string stripeSecretKey = configuration.GetSection("appSettings").GetSection("StripeSecretKey").Value;  //Configuration["stripeSecretKey"];

        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = stripeSecretKey;

        var oessConnectedAccount = request.ConnectedAccount;


        string desc = HttpContext.Request.Query["desc"].ToString();
        var oessDescription = request.Description;
        var callCurrency = request.PaymentCurrency;
        var oessDescriptor = request.Descriptor;
        var oessReceiptEmail = request.ArtistEmail;
        var oessPaymentAmount = request.PaymentAmount;

        Console.WriteLine("Ammount:" + oessPaymentAmount);

        var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
        PaymentIntent paymentIntent = null;
```

When I add a breakpoint on the last line I can see that the ConfirmPaymentRequest request is not returning any values when using my .NET 6.0 upgraded version. However the .NET 2.1 version does return the correct values.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is a compatibility issue...
Try upgrading your .NET Core to 3.1 or higher because that is what it says on NuGet website it is supported. than install the latest Stripe nuget either via package manager or .net CLI

PM

> NuGet\Install-Package Stripe.net -Version 43.18.0

.NET CLI

> dotnet add package Stripe.net --version 43.18.0

You can also check the [NuGet website for Stripe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net) as well and check if there is a version of stripe.net that supports your current version of .net core

Comment: Thank you Jakub. I have also tried upgrading to .net 6.0 and updated all the Nuget packages to the latest. Everything works except Stripe.

Comment: are you still getting the same error ? @AndyLaffan

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.